# Wordpress Error Message: Something went wrong when compiling less files. Operation on an invalid type

Tags: wordpress, themes

I was just setting up my wordpress site and I started to get an error on a white screen: Something went wrong when compiling less files. Operation on an invalid type

1. I disabled all plugins and activated them one by one - no change
2. I had recently upgraded to PHP 7.4 - I tested 7.3 and 7.0 - no change
3. I ran a debug and received the following error:
   Deprecated: Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ? d : e` is deprecated. Use either `(a ? b : c) ? d : e` or `a ? b : (c ? d : e)` in /xxx/xxxx/public_html/xxx.com/wp-content/themes/buddyapp/kleo-framework/lib/function-core.php on line 400

Hope you can help fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a problem with the code in your theme which looks to be a commercial theme, so you will need to get the theme developers to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Have reached out but help is slow. ;-(

Comment: I solved it by running a WP reset.